# How to delete all annotations excluding variations in Fritz

Tags: fritz

Suppose I load a game.

[image]

Now I want to delete all annotations only (excluding variations). What is the way to do it?

If I select, 'Delete All Commentary'

[image]

It removes both annotations and variations. Check screenshot.

[image]

How to remove annotations only or vice-versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to delete all annotations only (excluding variations). What is the way to do it?

The simple and obvious way to do this which works in all chess engine GUIs which support PGN is to save the game as PGN. PGN files are just text so you can then edit the file with a text editor and manually remove whatever you like, save it and then open again with Fritz or the GUI of your choice.

Comment: What if the file is not PGN?

Comment: @double-beep For Fritz the default is Chessbase format, i.e. cbh, I think. That is proprietary.

Comment: Yes, I mean, in that case it wouldn't be possible to edit it, since it's not a text file.

Comment: @double-beep Which is precisely why I say "save the game as PGN". All engine GUIs that I know have that as an option regardless of their default file format.

Answer (score 1):

If you can save the game as PGN then [pgn-extract](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/%7Edjb/pgn-extract/) has options to remove commentary, variations and NAGs, either separately or in combination. It's a free tool. Disclosure: I am the author of pgn-extract.

Comment: What you mean by NAGs? Notations?

Comment: NAG stands for Numeric Annotation Glyph (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_Annotation_Glyphs), things like $1 or ??. They are part of the PGN standard.